# r: ifelse() based on whether last digit of as.character is odd or even

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a list of (fake) social security numbers here

```
> df
          cpr
1 120234-1353
2 031254-4444
```

I want to create `df$sex` like a `ifelse()`-solution, so that `if` the last digit of the `character string` is odd, then `M` else `F`. How can this be done?

**Expected output**

```
> df
          cpr    sex
1 120234-1353      M
2 031254-4444      F
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(cpr = c("120234-1353", "031254-4444")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options for determining which end in an odd digit:

```r
(isoddend <- grepl("[13579]$", df$cpr))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
(isoddend <- substring(df$cpr, nchar(df$cpr)) %in% c("1","3","5","7","9"))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

From there, two ways to convert that to `"M"` and `"F"`:

```r
c("F", "M")[1 + isoddend]
# [1] "M" "F"
ifelse(isoddend, "M", "F")
# [1] "M" "F"
```

(There is no strict need to define `isoddend`, the actual code can go directly in the brackets `[.]` or `ifelse(.,`.)

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
transform(
  df,
  sex = ifelse(as.numeric(substr(cpr, nchar(cpr), nchar(cpr))) %% 2, "M", "F")
)
```

or shorter `ifelse` (thank @jay.sf's comment)

```
ifelse(as.double(substring(x, nchar(x))) %% 2, "M", "F")
```

gives

```
          cpr sex
1 120234-1353   M
2 031254-4444   F
```

Comment: Had a similar thing on the clipboard! `transform(df, sex=ifelse(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", cpr)) %% 2 == 0, "F", "M"))`.

Comment: @jay.sf Cool! Thanks for another option!